# jboss could not load logmanager

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I'm trying to enable JMX on a JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final "Brontes".
Sofar I edited the startup.conf in jboss/bin to hold these following lines:

```
# Enable JMX Remote
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

then on starting the jboss I got following error message:

```
> WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class
> org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/Level
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
>         at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:247)
>         at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.Level
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:395)
>         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>         ... 4 more
```

Then I added following lines to the standalone.conf

```
JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.logmanager"
```

and

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar"
```

but still I'm getting the error

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:191)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:846)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:450)
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
        at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:60)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeRepositorySelector.<clinit>(BridgeRepositorySelector.java:42)
        ... 7 more
```

Now I'm out of ideas what to do next. I haven't found anything on google either. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

For Wildly 14 you have to add Wildfly Commons and the Logmanager to the class path, hence the `JAVA_OPTS` looks like the following

```
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager 
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager 
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.4.Final.jar 
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/common/main/wildfly-common-1.4.0.Final.jar 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10001 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Xss512k 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=300 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with Java 11. "-Xbootclasspath/p" isn't a supported option anymore.

Comment: In Java 11 you can use "-Xbootclasspath/a". Just checkt it with 'java -X' to see the X options for your plataform.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this it got me to a point where I got my application to startup properly

my config:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar"
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when your wildfly server user does not have enough permissions to create the logManager file. You just need to give full access permission to your wildfly directory user. This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**for jboss eap7.2**, add these in the `standalone.conf.bat`.
This should expose your jmx metrics at http://127.0.0.1:9184/metric.

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true"
rem # Use jmx_prometheus_javaagents-0
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:path_to_your_jmx_exporter\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.18.0.jar=0.0.0.0:9184:path_to_your_jmx_configuration\config.yaml"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath/p:%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\wildfly\common\main\wildfly-common-1.4.0.Final-redhat-1.jar"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath/p:%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-2.1.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar"
```