# JBoss 7.1.0.EAP could not load LogManager

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, jmx

I am trying to enable jmx port in my Linux7.1 box which has JBoss 7.1.0.EAP server.
I have edited the bin/standalone.conf file with the following:
The first JAVA_OPTS is running fine, but when its time to load the logmanager its giving the following error

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar"
```

On starting the server, I am getting the following error:

````
```
 JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/software/jboss_ased_ai_icame_dev-1

  JAVA: /opt/software/jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:"/opt/software/jboss_ased_ai_icame_dev-1/standalone/log/gc.log" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms6145m -Xmx6145m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:846)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
May 27, 2020 12:11:41 AM org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1
May 27, 2020 12:11:41 AM org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService start
INFO: WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) starting
May 27, 2020 12:11:42 AM org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1 run
ERROR: WFLYCTL0002: Error booting the container
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:316)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:329)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.<init>(ConvertUtilsBean.java:154)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.uri.BeanSupport.<clinit>(BeanSupport.java:35)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.MessageLoadBalancingType.<clinit>(MessageLoadBalancingType.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320)
        at java.lang.System$2.getEnumConstantsShared(System.java:1249)
        at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse(EnumSet.java:407)
        at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:110)
        at java.util.EnumSet.allOf(EnumSet.java:131)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.operations.validation.EnumValidator.<init>(EnumValidator.java:107)
        at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.ClusterConnectionDefinition.<clinit>(ClusterConnectionDefinition.java:125)
        at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.MessagingSubsystemParser_2_0.getParserDescription(MessagingSubsystemParser_2_0.java:358)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.PersistentResourceXMLParser.readElement(PersistentResourceXMLParser.java:41)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.PersistentResourceXMLParser.readElement(PersistentResourceXMLParser.java:35)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_5.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml_5.java:610)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_5.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_5.java:243)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_5.readElement(StandaloneXml_5.java:142)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
        at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:57)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.JBossLogFactory.<init>(JBossLogFactory.java:48)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Holder.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:42)


```
````

Can anybody help on what I am doing wrong?

I tried this solution of adding the Package like mentioned in 
[jboss could not load logmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093456/jboss-could-not-load-logmanager)
but still the issue is coming

Comment: JMX should be enabled by default so you shouldn't need any of those properties set. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: we are getting memory full in the server almost 90%..want to get a heap dump to analyse the memory footprint

Comment: You probably need to expose the management address, `-bmanagement=0.0.0.0`, so it exposes the JMX endpoint. You won't need those other JMX settings.

Comment: where do I expose the management address?

Comment: You can pass that `-bmanagement=0.0.0.0` to the command line when starting the server or you can update the configuration. Just note that 0.0.0.0 exposes all IP addresses.